# Getting a column header from the min value, excluding zero

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet to find the best price of a product in Google Sheets. I have the product description on B column, starting from the sixth row and below, the prices are on column E6 and on, (F6, G6, H6,...) Each supplier name is written on the fist row of their Columns. The lowest price is in column C and Column D displays the supplier with that price.

I've tried the min() function, but there's an issue, I need it to bypass 0 values.

On column C, I'm using this code `=min($E6:$Z6)`  and for displaying the supplier I'm using `=index($E$1:$Z$1,0,match(min($E6:$Z6),$E6:$Z6,0))`
I'll add a screenshot of the problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

wrap it into simple `IF` or `IFERROR`

```
=IF(MIN($E6:$Z6)=0, , MIN($E6:$Z6))
```

and the second one:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$1:$Z$1, 0, MATCH(MIN($E6:$Z6), $E6:$Z6, 0)))
```

Comment: That only hides zero value cells, but the second one uses those zeros even if they're hidden. I tried =min(filter($E$6:$Z$6,$E$6:$Z$6<>0))   but the second one gets a little messy, I can't get it to work, =index($E$6:$Z$6,0,match(min(filter($E6:$Z6<>0),$E6:$Z6,0)))